# How can i update(increase one) int value by using sql command?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I declared a column as Survey_Answer1Count in my database and i try to increase it's number by one. So how can i write it's sql command. Survey_Answer1Count is int value. I tried this :

```
string  queryIncrease = "update SurveyCount 
    set Answer2Count =  Answer2Count + 1 
    where Survey_Title = '" + lbl_title.Text + "' 
        and Survey_Adder = '" + lbl_adder.Text + "'";
```

Comment: Are you executing that SQL? It looks ok.

Comment: This should work fine.  Does the command give you an error when you execute it in code?

Comment: Thank you so i have different problem.

Comment: @user1908327 Can you show the resulting string that is sent instead of that? It could be that what's in those variables upset the SQL.

Comment: DO NOT LEAVE YOUR CODE LIKE THIS. You should always use SQL parameters to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities. If someone got `'; drop table SurveyCount; --` into lbl_title.Text somehow, your SurveyCount table will be deleted. More at http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/113/Preventing-SQL-Injection-in-ASP.NET

Comment: @JohnGibb How did you check that lbl_title.Text and lbl_adder.Text aren't already sanitized?

Comment: Except for the column name you mention is different from the column name in the sql, this looks fine. What happened when you tried this code?

Comment: @popnoodles maybe they are, but it's a lot safer to just use '@surveyTitle' and '@surveyAdder' and pass them as parameters.

Comment: @JohnGibb ok, so you just forgot the to say If your haven't already sanitized that code...

Comment: @popnoodles No, I think that you should use parameterization anyway. It doesn't rely on praying that somewhere else in your code base .Text is NEVER assigned unsanitized user input. It also enables query plan reuse. Why *not* use parameterization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid potential SQL Injection issues use a parameterized query instead, like this:

```
string queryIncrease = "UPDATE SurveyCount SET Answer2Count = Answer2Count + 1 
WHERE Survey_Title = @Title AND Survey_Adder = @Adder";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryIncrease, YOURSQLCONNECTION))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", lbl_title.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adder", lbl_adder.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way, be sure to replace the connection string where I put "put connection string here"

```
string  queryIncrease = "update SurveyCount set Answer2Count =  Answer2Count + 1 where Survey_Title = '" + lbl_title.Text + "' and Survey_Adder = '" + lbl_adder.Text + "'";

using (var SqlConn = new SqlConnection(put connection string here))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryIncrease, SqlConn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 100000;

        if (SqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            SqlConn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()       
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you should parameterize your query to avoid injection, as a comment above said, so throw that in the mix as well! :)